# How to increase code font size in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I tried doing it via Appearances as shown, but this seems to not affect code font or size

[image]

How can this be done please?

Comment: To expand upon this topic, it would be really nice if the font size of comments could be changed, irrespective of the code's font size. This would increase the readability of the code. I've put in a feature request :)
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-188012

Answer (score 105, accepted):

While I was waiting for someone to respond, I looked around a bit more and found the answer.

Navigate to Fonts and change font to whatever size you'd like

[image]

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-editor-font.html

Comment: You have to create your own font to change the font size.

Comment: before modifying, save it as yours

Comment: Funny, a lot of these other suggestions didn't work - I suppose the UI has changed over the years...   Thanks bro !

Answer (score 362):

It's as simple as **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + mouse wheel**. If this doesn't work for you, enable *File* → *Settings* → *Editor* → *General* → (checked) *Change font size (Zoom) with Ctrl+Mouse Wheel*.

Comment: On idea 14, Go to File -> Settings -> And then enter the search phraze "zoom". The correct tick box is shown in Editor -> General section.

Comment: It is required to enable the option in 14.1.2 after CTRL + SHIFT + A -> Mouse Change font size.

Comment: Of note is that the color scheme may have a different font than the default. To change this, go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme Font, and either set it to use the default, or also change the font size value found here.

Comment: Is there an option to change the font size globally with a hotkey?

Comment: I can confirm what Tomasz Waszczyk wrote: you have to select the checkbox first, to allow mouse scroll wheel to change font size. After I set this, I can now scroll in and out to increase the text font. (Not sure why this is not enabled by default; to me this seems like a useful default, since I need this all the time in other editors and IDEs too.)

Comment: What about on a touchpad?

Comment: On MacOs it's `CMD`+`mouse wheel` (and first enable option "Change font size with Command+Mouse wheel in:")

Answer (score 122):

It is possible to change font size etc when creating custom Scheme using `Save As...` button:

[image: Save As...]

Comment: You need to take following path: File  >  Settings  > Editor  >   Colors & Fonts >  Font --- [Size] .. You will be able to change the size after you use `save as` option

Comment: Keep in my mind you have to reopen any files you had open to see the change made by this setting. Confused me for a second.

Answer (score 94):

**To change font size using the keyboard**

In Windows or Linux press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

In MAC press <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

In the popup frame, type `Increase font size` or `Decrease font size`, and then click Enter.

Font grows larger or smaller.

Comment: This worked for me when mouse wheel didn't (in the Tail File pane, PhpStorm 2016.1.1 Build #PS-145.970 on mac). Thanks!

Comment: Cmd+Shift+A for those on mac

Comment: The bad thing about this solution is that the font size change is not applied on all files of the editor

Answer (score 36):

To change the font size in the current version of IntelliJ IDEA, go to File → Settings → Editor → General. In the dialog box, and check the item labeled "Change font size (Zoom) with Ctrl+Mouse Wheel".

Comment: The bad thing about this solution is that the font size change is not applied on all files of the editor.

Comment: Yeah that's a real antifeature. You have to close the files and open them again...

Comment: duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14529131/548473

Answer (score 26):

**In IntellJ 13**

```
File 
 |
  ---- Settings 
       |
        ------- Editor
                 |
                  ------- Colors & Fonts
                          |
                           ------ Font -> [Size]
```

[image]

Comment: Just as an update: I installed Rider, and doing this work as long as I closed all open files. For new opened it worked.

Answer (score 21):

For Intellij 2018 it's quite confusing as there's an **Editor → Font** section but it's usually overriden by **Editor → Color Scheme → Color Scheme Font**:

[image]

Comment: this way changes will persist after restart too

Answer (score 16):

On a Mac you can also pinch-zoom, i.e. move your thumb and index finger together or apart.

Comment: Works in IntelliJ 2018.3 on MacOS

Comment: The nice and simple answer but you have to do the same in all the files you will work on.

Answer (score 16):

On Mac Os, go to **Preferences > Editor > Font > Size** . Enter the new font size.

More details [read this blog post](https://blog.raychenon.com/intellij-bigger-font-size/)

Curious how it's done on Linux and Windows

[image]

Answer (score 15):

On Mac:
IntelliJ Idea → Preferences

[image]

In the Preferences Dialog,

1. Editor → Colors & Fonts → Font.
2. Click on Save As, enter the scheme name such as the mac user name.
3. Change the Size as required.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

As of `InteliJ IDEA 2017.2.5`, you can change the **editor font size** by going to:

<kbd>Settings</kbd> ▶ <kbd>Editor</kbd> ▶ <kbd>Font</kbd>

[image]

Comment: In my case there was - for whatever reason - another font set in "Color Scheme Font". Maybe you want to mention that one needs to untick the checkbox there to override the default font

Answer (score 10):

First press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

then search increase font
 [image]

For Mac Users, It's `cmd + shift + A`

Comment: this also has the disadvantage of applying only to the current editor (i.e. not global setting).

Answer (score 9):

The font used in menus, dialogs and tool windows can be changed in **Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Use custom font**.[image: Setting dialog]

Answer (score 8):

Shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> - Then Type Increase font size then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: The bad thing about this solution is that the font size change is not applied on all files of the editor.

Comment: Duplicated answer

Answer (score 8):

There are two places where you can change the appearance:

1. File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Appearance -> Use custom font -> Size

[GUI size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niCCc.png)

2. File -> Settings -> Editor -> Font -> Size

[Editor Font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJiId.png)

The first controls the font size of IntelliJ GUI (menus etc).
The second one is for the editor.

Comment: Thank you! I was struggling to find how to change the GUI size. I wish there was a way to just `cmd + '+'` to change the entire application font size all at one.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is very late answer, yet people are still asking this question, so it may help.

In newer versions of IntelliJ (e.g. 2022.2), besides described techniques, one can globally change the font size with two keystrokes:

- To increase the font size: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> / <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>
- To decrease the font size: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> / <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

Comment: reference: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/2022-2/#user-experience

Answer (score 6):

It's not possible. Please, [vote for the bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-69802).

Comment: Possible now, but I only found the solution thanks to the tracking/bug link posted here.  Solution (verified in Android Studio) is posted here http://stackoverflow.com/a/37145459/2162226

Comment: this bug was in 2011. See my answer.

Comment: @RaymondChenon the answer is outdated. please delete

Answer (score 4):

You can use Presentation Mode to temporarily increase the font size.

**Note:** The location of this menu has changed. It's nearer the top.

Enable Presentation Mode with View -> Enter Presentation Mode

[image: View menu]

I needed to increase the default font size for presentation mode. To do this, open Settings and typed "presentation mode" in the search bar. Under appearance, scroll down to Presentation Mode, and select your preferred font size.

[image: Presentation font settings]

Because I use it frequently, I mapped "toggle presentation mode" to Ctrl-P. Under "Keymap", right-click on "Toggle Presentation mode" and select "Add keyboard shortcut"

[image: Keymap for presentation mode]

Literally press the Control and P keys and then hit OK to enable this.

Answer (score 3):

On Intellij Idea 3.3(Ultimate)
System : Mac

IntelliJ Idea → Preferences (<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>) → Editor → General(Main) : Uncheck/Check "Change font size(Zoon) with Command + Mouse Wheel"

Answer (score 3):

CTRL+SHIFT+A type `increase` and press Enter, repeat by just pressing again CTRL+SHIFT+A and then Enter until you are satisfied

[image: run anything, increase font]

If you need to do it often than add a custom shortcut to it :

[image: Add custom shortcut]

Alt +  Num pad +   and Alt +  Num pad -  are free

Answer (score 2):

> **For newest version of IntelliJ, i think option has changed a bit.**

## Screenshot:

[image]

**My current version of IntelliJ:**

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.5 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-173.4674.33, built on March 6, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b15 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change keymaps you can quickly enter and exit Presentation Mode via the following shortcut sequence (use Ctrl in macOS, too):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>   (Switch...)
2. <kbd>4</kbd>   (View Mode)
3. <kbd>1</kbd>   (Enter/Exit Presentation Mode)

Answer (score 0):

Goto->Settings->Editor->Fonts->Schemes option. Then rename that options and apply, then choose the new option (renamed one) then option to edit font size will be enable.

Answer (score 0):

Change the "Color Scheme Font". and you will get what you want. I have faced the same issue and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

So there are several ways you can do it:

1. Windows or Linux press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> 
   In the popup frame, type `Increase font size` or `Decrease font size`, and then click Enter
2. go to `File → Settings → Editor → General`. In the dialog box, and check the item labeled "`Change font size (Zoom)` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse Wheel</kbd>"
   [image]
3. go to `File → Settings → Editor → Font`. Change the font size and click OK/Apply button. 
   [image]

Comment: Duplicated answer

Comment: @GrigoryKislin in the recent past there are a lot of changes in IntelliJ UI. That's why I attached pics with new IntelliJ IDE to make it more visible and helpful for new programmer

Answer (score 0):

In 2021-12, Pycharm 2021.3 (Professional Edition) and probably community edition as well, you can activate the ability to zoom in and out on the current or all files by:

> File > Settings > Editor > General > Mouse Control

and checking off

> Change font size with Ctrl + Mouse Wheel In

Comment: Duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14529131/548473

Comment: Hey there! I wasn't able to find this SO post/question when I looked this up on behalf of OP. I'd argue that generally those googling this question wouldn't know that a post about IntelliJ would apply to Pycharm and therefore not make it a duplicate, but I could see arguments against that POV.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, there is setting for **global change** of font size with mouse scroll. This is implemented **since IntelliJ IDEA version 2021.3**.
In section *Settings* -> *Editor* -> *General* -> *Mouse control* you have to select both "*Change font size with Ctrl+Mouse Wheel*" and the radio option
"*All editors*".
[image: All editors]
*Source*: (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/2021-3/)

Sadly, it seems that this does not affect zoom from keyboard *Ctrl* + *Numpad+/-*.

Also note that sometimes there might be an **issue** when you have many open editors. The IDE **freezes with high CPU** after Ctrl+scroll and has to be killed. Workaround is to close most of the code editors, apply the resize and then reopen them, for example with recent windows (Ctrl+E).
*Link*: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-283722

Answer (score 0):

I use the Ctrl+Mouse wheel like said in the docs. Perfectly quick when I share my big screen 32 inches to a peple with 15 inch laptop.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Zooming_in_the_Editor.html

[image]

It is possible to increase the font size of the active tab or on all tabs.

Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Just to also mention the font size of the "[render preview](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/03/intellij-idea-2020-1-eap8/#in_editor_javadocs_rendering)", which displays comments as formatted text. Unfortunately this is not affected by the global font size. But it's possible to change it with the
**right-click context-menu** of the rendered comment:
[image: screenshot]
An issue is to enhance the font change to
"Make rendered JavaDoc font size bigger/smaller when zooming in/out on code"
is already opened: [IDEA-238153](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-238153/Make-rendered-JavaDoc-font-size-bigger-smaller-when-zooming-in-out-on-code)

Answer (score 0):

It's simple !!

Alt + shift + comma => decrease the font size in IntelliJ

Alt + shift + 'Full stop' => Increase the font size in IntelliJ