# IntelliJ how to zoom in / out

Tags: intellij-idea, zooming

The IntelliJ keymap says:

```
Zoom in: Keypad +  =  
Zoom out Keypad - -
```

But they have no effect. Anyone have this working?

New info: Now I have added more key-bindings:

```
Zoom in: Alt-Shift-= 
Zoom out: Alt-Shift-minus
```

But these still have no effect. Does zoom in/zoom out even work at all in IntelliJ?

Comment: Where are you seeing these keymaps? Are they for a plugin?

Comment: no i a referring to the general IJ keymap  File|Settings|Keymap

Comment: I see no keymaps with the keyword "zoom" in them in v12.1.4. The only zooming capability I am aware of is with `Ctrl+Mouse Wheel` if you enable **Change font size (Zoom) with `Ctrl+Mouse Wheel`** under _Settings|Editor_

Comment: @damo:  it is the very last option under Other.  In any case,  thanks for the tiop on the Ctrl+Mouse wheel: that does the trick.  If you put an official "answer" i will mark it as correct.

Comment: I'm not seeing the option...weird!

Comment: By the way, the `Zoom In/Out` options you are seeing are for UML Diagrams. I wasn't seeing the options because I have the UML Support plugin disabled.

Comment: All is said in IntelliJ's online doc there : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/zooming-in-the-editor.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Double click `Shift` to open the quick actions. Then search for "Decrease Font Size" or "Increase Font Size" and hit `Enter`. To repeat the action you can doubleclick `Shift` and `Enter`

I prefer that way because it works even when you're using not your own Computer without opening settings. Also works without leaving fullscreen, which is useful if you are live coding.

Comment: Oh that tip about `Repeat the action you can doubleclick Shift and Enter` is really nice one!

Answer (score 181):

You need to look for the `Increase Font Size` and `Decrease Font Size` options on the Keymap menu, you can see the options on my screenshot. You will find the Keymap menu under `Preferences > Keymap`.

[image: font size settings]

Assigning on those will have the expected effect for font zoom.

Comment: Nice! It looks like these actions were added in a recent update: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-84884

Comment: I needed the Reset Font Size so badly :D

Comment: I have set these and they have no effect. What is up with that ..  Update: there are many combinations that do not work on this. Try a few to find ones that DO work. This is a buggy feature.

Comment: This is the true answer as far as I am concerned

Comment: @RicardoE Also If you want to reset font size (like `Ctrl+0` in web browsers), you can add a keymap on `Settings -> Keymap -> Editor Actions -> Reset Font Size`

Comment: If you're using the preferences search bar to find this setting (i.e. searching 'font'), make sure you've clicked on Keymap. It won't come up if you're in Appearance, Editor, or another sub-menu.

Comment: Note that such action will work only for current editor, not for all. You may also use _Ctrl/Cmd_+_Mouse wheel_. For all editors there is another radio option to be selected. Link for details: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/73037353/841050)

Answer (score 151):

### **Update: This answer is old. Intellij has since added actions to adjust font size. Check out [Wilker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26436771/1671856) for assigning the new actions to keymaps.**

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+`Mouse Wheel` which can be enabled under File > Settings... > Editor > General : **Change font size (Zoom) with `Ctrl+Mouse Wheel`**

Comment: the problem here is to return the font to the original size, while pinching on the trackpad uses the original as the minimum, this is not true for the mouse zoom, so, how do you return the font size to original?

Comment: @WilkerLucio I just zoom in or out until it's back to normal. Other than that, I'm not sure. I recommend asking a new question or contacting intellij support if there's a better way.

Comment: actually I found my answer, what happens is that they introduced new keymaps for the text size, but the "zoom" is for the images, the one for text size is the "Increase Font Size" and "Decrease Font Size", assigning maps for those works as expected. I made a reply posting my findinds here, with screenshot, you can check it out :)

Comment: **Reset font size** by: 1) **Ctrl+Shift+A**, 2) type **Reset font size** and hit Enter. [more here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/zooming-in-the-editor.html)

Comment: 2017: Settings > Editor > General > Change font size (Zoom) with Ctrl+Mouse Wheel

Comment: You are the life saviour

Comment: For anyone else on MacOS, use the trackpad instead of the mouse scrollwheel for more granular scrolling.

Comment: Sadly this only changes the editor font size - not all the many other windows.

Answer (score 28):

*As Mark Amery suggested in comment,  original answer is no longer working here is working solution:*

### Answer for IntelliJ IDEA 2022 and later

Right now the best way to switch it on is:

**Double click `shift`, type `wheel` and switch `change font size...` to `ON`**

[image]

---

---

---

### Old Answer forIntelliJ IDEA <=2021

**Double click `shift`, type `zoom` and switch zoom to `on`**

[image]

Comment: Typing "Zoom" specifically will no longer find this in more recent versions of IDEA, as the parenthesized "Zoom" has been removed from the name of this setting.

Comment: For Mac, 2022, the default of `Ctrl + Shift + .` does Increase; `Ctrl + Shift + ,` does Decrease. Considering what Shift normally does, think of it as `Ctrl + >` (Increase); `Ctrl + <` (Decrease).

Comment: this should be top answer

Answer (score 26):

Update for intellij idea 2017 3.2

[image: Intellij idea 2017 3.2]

Answer (score 8):

Before User Shift + = or Shift - , you have to first set the key map as mentioned below  [image]

Answer (score 5):

File>Settings...>Editor>General>

then you'll find this in the menu Mouse,

"change the font size(Zoom) with Ctrl+Mouse Wheel"

Answer (score 4):

On the latest version 2022.2

The default on editor is;

Zoom out --- Alt + Shift + ,(comma)
Zoom in  --- Alt + Shift + .(full stop)

Answer (score 3):

1. Open `Preferences`
2. Under `Editor` → `General`
3. Check the checkbox `Change font size with Command + Mouse Wheel`
4. On the editor use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Mouse Wheel</kbd> (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Mouse Wheel</kbd>) to zoom in and out

[image: change_font_size]

Comment: thx but I don't have / use a mouse-wheel : the direct shortcuts are needed.

Comment: In my version (IDEA 2021.3.3 running on Ubuntu) the "Preferences" menu mentioned here is instead called "Settings" (accessed via the "File" menu or CTRL+ALT+S) and the setting here allows changing font size with CTRL+Mouse Wheel instead of Command+Mouse Wheel. Still, works for me, and probably the nicest solution for the fraction of users, like me, for whom this specific shortcut is the one they want.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have a similar view regarding the zoom functionality as I have in this picture:

[image]

Now if you mark one of the `Zoom In`/`Zoom Out` lines and choose `Add Keyboard Shortcut`:

[image]

You will find that this particular shortcut `Numpad +` is already occupied so there is a conflict:

[image]

So you'll just have assign this `Zoom In`/`Zoom Out` to some other keyboard shortcut:

[image]

Comment: I upvoted because did not know you could right click to add shortcut. But as mentioned in OP simply assigning a new keystroke did not fix issue.

Answer (score 0):

actually if you press

> Ctrl+`

and chose presentation view or one other view, it works pretty well!!

Comment: Presentation View in Intellij is without exaggeration the  most dangerous feature to use in any application I am aware of on the mac - in my 9 years using that O/S as my primary tool.  It twice caused a system lockup at the start of a formal conference talk for me.  I have disabled the shortcut  to get into presentation mode.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use CTRL + Mousewheel Up for Font Increase and CTRL + Mousewheel Down for font decrease.  It is fast and much simpler.

Ctrl+Alt+S, then search for increase/decrease.

Most programs have Ctrl +/- for "zoom" just works a little differently with IntelliJ

Comment: thx but using the mouse for anything is a drag to keyboardist me.