# Intellij zoom font all tabs

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to have Intellij zoom (aka adjust the font size) on all tabs at the same time? Can't seem to find the option anywhere.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot zoom in/out for all files/documents without changing the the default font size in the settings.

To change the default font size (for all opened files) open **Settings** dialog (<kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> on *MacOS* or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> on *Windows OS*).

Then go to **Settings → Editor → Color Scheme → Color Scheme Font** and change font size there:

[image]

This will set the default font size in intelliJ IDEA.

*Note:* If the value field is inactive, you need to create a new Schema first by clicking **Save As...** button.

---

You can also enable scrolling zoom (only the current file will be affected). Go to **Settings → Editor → General** and activate the checkbox **Change font size (Zoom) with Ctrl + Mouse Wheel** right under the **Mouse** section:

[image]

Now you can change the font size with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+**Mouse Wheel**. However this approach will change font size for each tab individually.

Comment: Maybe I should have been more clear. I am trying to see if the scrolling zoom can be done on all tabs at once.

Comment: You can do it for each tab separately with Ctrl + Mouse Wheel. I've updated my answer, please check.

Comment: This answer is useful, but doesn't appear to answer the actual question which relates to changing the zoom level on all docs at the same time.

Comment: @peteski Actually the first part of the answer completely covers the question, the second part is just another handy way.

Comment: @DimaSan I disagree, since the question asked "Is there a way to have Intellij zoom.. ", the first part is not allowing zoom in/out, but just changing the settings in general. the 2nd part is better but only applies to a single open document. I guess what I'm saying is, maybe the answer should start by saying: You cannot zoom in/out for all files/documents without changing the settings. the 2 parts of your answer are valid work arounds

Comment: @peteski Well, if you put it that way, I agree - this is not a Zoom tool, but rather option to change the font size. I'll update the answer - thanks.

Comment: @DimaSan thanks, it's a good answer btw, nicely written. Sorry I think I went a bit hard earlier. My bad.

Comment: @peteski that's okay, no problem, you just point me to make it better. Cheers

Comment: I'm starting to dislike this IDE more and more. Lots of basic stuff is infeasible. For example, file syncing is horrendously slow (you'll lose literally hours) - why can't they just do rsync, which is fast?

Answer (score 2):

This is finally implemented **since Intellij IDEA 2021.3**.

You have to chose new radio button next to mouse wheel setting.
Link to detailed answer in similar question: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/73037353/841050).

*Announcement*: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/2021-3/