# Rider editor zoomed in

Tags: rider

After zooming in on macOS for Rider to make the font bigger, I can't zoom out and reset it to the 13px default size. Normally it could, but now not anymore. What can I do?

[image]

Comment: Nevermind, I found it at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176048/intellij-zoom-font-all-tabs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intellij zoom font all tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176048/intellij-zoom-font-all-tabs)